# Dumping postgres DB, time and .sql file weight

Tags: postgresql, dump

I have a big db (nominatim db, for address geocoding reverse), is about 408gb big.

Now, to provide an estimate to the customer, I would like to know how long will take the export/reimport procedure and how big will .sql dump file be.
My postgresql version is 9.4, is installed on a centOS 6.7 virtual machine, with 16gb RAM and 500 gb disk space.

Can you help me?

Thank you all guys for your answer, anyway to restore the dumped db I don't use the command `pg_restore` but `psql -d newdb -f dump.sql` (I read this way to do in a official doc). This because I have to set-up this db on another machine to avoid the nominatim db indexing procedure! I don't know if someone knows nominatim (is a openstreetmap opensource product) but the db indexing process of European map (15.8 gb), in a CentOS 6.7 machine with 16gb ram tooks me 32 days...
Than another possible question should be: `pg_restore` is equal to `psql -d -f`? Wich is faster?

Thanks again

Comment: This depends on too many factors that are unique to your environment, so it's essentially impossible to answer.

Answer (score 8):

As [@a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) says, nobody will be able to give you exact answers for your environment. But this is the procedure I would use to get some estimates.

I have generally found that a compressed backup of my data is 1/10th or less the size of the live database. You can also usually deduct the on-disk size of the indexes from the backup size as well. [Examine the size of things in-database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-admin.html) to get a better idea. You can also try forming a subset of the database you have which is much smaller and compare the live size to the compressed backup; this may give you a ratio that should be in the ballpark. SQL files are gassy and compress well; the on-disk representation Postgres uses seems to be even gassier though. Price of performance probably.

The best way to estimate time is just to do some exploratory runs. In my experience this usually takes longer than you expect. I have a ~1 TB database that I'm fairly sure would take about a month to restore, but it's also aggressively indexed. I have several ~20 GB databases that backup/restore in about 15 minutes. So it's pretty variable, but indexes add time. If you can set up a similar server, you can try the backup-restore procedure and see how long it will take. I would recommend doing this anyway, just to build confidence and suss out any lingering issues before you pull the trigger.

I would also recommend you try out [`pg_dump`'s "custom format"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html) (`pg_dump -Fc`) which makes compressed archives that are easy for [`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) to use.